# Unable to toggle between input methods using Fcitx

Tags: language-support, input-language, fcitx, system-language

I'm using fcitx for system input and I have more than one language installed.

I cannot toggle between different languages with the correct hot key. Explicitly clicking the "input method" in the drop down menu bar doesn't work either, the "input method" option simply doesn't expand upon clicking.

[image: Fcitx menu bar]

Yet going into "configure" I do see the other languages installed, and the only way to use any other language, is to put that language as the 1st preference in the configure menu.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what's your OS?

Answer (score 1):

I use fcitx for chinese input method on `Ubuntu 18.04`, and I once had problem toggling the chinese input method too (with `Super+Space`). As I could not replicate the condition easily, here I recall how I made it work. (**Notice**: I feel that fcitx or input method on Ubuntu is a little buggy, sometimes this might not work)

1. Update input method

   1. open `Input Method` from *Show Applications*
   2. select OK and then Yes to manually choose an input method
   3. select `fcitx`, and finish the rest choice.
   4. Probably log out X session and then log in.
2. Disable shortcut in system settings (launch from Applications)

   1. disable (Switch to next input source) `Super+Space` in Setttings -> Device -> Keyboard -> Typing
3. Set up fcitx shortcut

   1. launch `Fcitx Configue Tool`
   2. set Global Config -> Trigger Input Method

---

PS. I don't know when there is need to reboot or relogin, so be more pacient and give it shot.